# Вопрос про админки в Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Здравствуйте, нужно понять, какая сейчас админка:

1) поддерживает Ruby On Rails последней версии под номером 4.2

2) русифицированная, вместе с ошибками валидации, либо понять как это сделать максимально просто и быстро и какими gem'ами нужно догнаться

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Хорошая админка - это Active Admin.
[Active admin документация](http://activeadmin.info/docs/documentation.html)

Все это ставится с гемом Devise. С моей версией ruby 2.2.1 версия Devise

```
gem 'devise', '~> 3.4.1'
```

[хороший туториал по настройке Devise](http://habrahabr.ru/post/208056/)

В итоге в гем файле должно выглядеть как-то так:

```
gem 'activeadmin', github: 'activeadmin'
gem 'devise', '~> 3.4.1'
```

Answer (score 3):

Я в большинстве проектов использую https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin
Работает в содружестве с гемом `devise`, поэтому его также придётся добавить в `Gemfile`

Answer (score 3):

Еще есть очень простая и удобная админка rails_admin: https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin

Интегрируется с Devise (для регистрации и аутентификации), Papertail (для хранения истории изменений) и Cancan (для разделения прав пользователей)